# Behavior of $_POST variable in PHP

Tags: php, forms, post, superglobals

This is probably a simple question: how does PHP's `$_POST` superglobal variable behave with PHP across multiple files within one session?

The manual on PHP.net states this: `"This is a 'superglobal', or automatic global, variable. This simply means that it is available in all scopes throughout a script."`

Here is my specific situation: I have one page that primarily contains `HTML` with multiple forms - which are handled with jQuery. I then have an "intermediate" page that calls my `PHP` class. Those two files continue the user's current session. Obviously, `$_POST` is utilized extensively.

I am curious if `$_POST` will "refresh" itself each time a form is submitted, or if it will add new identifiers in the array.

For instance,

Form Submission One => `$_POST = $POST['firstname'], $POST['lastname']...`
Form Submission Two => `$_POST = $POST['firstname'], $POST['lastname']...+ $_POST['Id'], $_POST['whatever']...`

Any input is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

`$_POST` is populated from posted variables for that specific HTTP request.  If you have multiple requests happening, then they will each have their own `$_POST`.

Nothing is implicitly shared between requests.  You must use session data for that.

Answer (score 1):

The `$_POST` variable is created for each query, based on the content inbound POSTed in the form.  It will not persist between calls (that's `$_SESSION`, and it behaves differently).

It's not that `$_POST` refreshes on each form post, but rather that it is created uniquely for each HTTP POST transaction.